# MST Feature not being applied

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

Is there a way to make sure a feature always gets applied?

Here is the issue.  I have written C# code to generate a MST for an MSI based on a REG file and allowing the user to assign property values.

I want to do something like:

1. Create a temp MSI to work in
2. Create a new feature based on the .REG filename (Prepend REG_ drop .REG, spaces to _, remove other non-alpha-numeric characters) and assign it as a child of the first feature
   found in the MSI that does not have a parent.
3. Create a new component for the registry entries
4. Assign the component to the feature in the feature components
   table
5. I create the registry and remove registry tables based on the .REG
   file setting the component from step 4.
6. Generate the transform.

I can't get the above to work, BUT if I pick an existing feature instead of creating a new one, it works.  The parent feature does get installed, but not the new feature.  I'm guessing I'm setting one of the fields wrong.

Feature fields are something like:

```
    Feature:         REG_HKLM_Settings
    Feature_Parent:  Default_Feature  
    Title:            
    Description:      
    Display:          
    Level:           1
    Directory:       TARGETDIR
    Attributes:      0
```

The above works for most MSI's.  The MSI I am having issues with has about 20 features.  I'm trying to avoid adding a dialog where the user has to select an existing feature...  What I would really like to do is create a new feature that gets installed no mater what.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - For the new feature, do not set a parent, set level to 1, and attributes to 0.  Setting Directory seems to be optional.